# Accepting transaction signature via web3 with metamask

Tags: web3js, metamask

I am using uniswap swap functions on web3 and I wanted to accept the transaction directly on code without using the pop up prompt on metamask. Is there a way to do this? or other alternative/workaround to make it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always create a custom client-side wallet in JavaScript/HTML/web3.js that holds the private key in localStorage to make the transactions, separate from the private key from MetaMask.

Then you ask users to transfer assets to this wallet.

However, the practice is not encouraged, as it is unsafe. [EtherDelta had such functionality](https://www.reddit.com/r/EtherDelta/comments/6zmep1/is_it_safe_to_enter_my_private_key_to_etherdelta/). They got [hacked in 2017](https://mashable.com/2017/12/21/etherdelta-hacked/) and users having their private keys on the website wallet lost their assets.